# Set up basic environment of AWS without freetier

Tags: amazon-web-services

i am newbie to use AWS system.
well, my freetier is just expired recently.

so far, i run an instance all day and use ssh to make code there.
but now, i realized it could charge me more than i expected. so i decided to terminate the instance.

1. then, how can i connect to instance easily? do i need to turn it on everytime i want to code?
2. And which is better? whether using DynamicDB(in AWS) or make a separated instance and install linux and mongodb(or something else).

Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

Best practices to save on cost is to stop (not terminate) your instance when you are not using it.

You will not pay for your instance in STOPped mode.  You will just pay for the storage of your EBS volumes (boot drive).

When you Terminate your instance, you cannot restart it.  If you Terminate you instance, be sure your data are saved on a secondary EBS volume or a snapshot or stored on S3.

Regarding your second question, it really depends on your application needs : at what scale do you expect to run ?  How large will be your data store ? What type of query are you going to perform ?

For most cases, DynamoDB will be more cost effective than running a couple of EC2 instances with a Mongo DB cluster.  And you will not need to maintain and to operate the infrastructure, AWS will do it for you.

You might have other point of view from this question : [DynamoDB vs MongoDB NoSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931073/dynamodb-vs-mongodb-nosql)

Comment: Thanks a lot!, i have one more question =)
Then.. do i need to "Un"stop(?) everytime i want to use?

or.. can i wake the instance up with ssh like a script. so that i could do that easily.

Comment: You will need to start the instance before to connect to it. Just like you start your PC in the morning. You can use the web console or the command line interface installed on your laptop or the iOS or Android mobile application to do so

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to just use MongoHQ: https://bridge.mongohq.com/signup

If you're interested in learning how to set up the servers, digitalocean is a good bet as they don't charge you for the IOPS and give you SSDs on the instance:

http://www.digitalocean.com

Enjoy!