# Can we use spot instances for database servers and Kafka etc.?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is it okay to use spot instances for database servers, for example for Mongodb cluster nodes? Or is it advisable to use spot instances for Messaging systems like Kafka,  Configuration/Service discovery system like Consul etc.?

Answer (score 2):

The primary caution that AWS advises customers to remember is if you decide to bid on spot instances, make sure that your processing planned for those instances ***can be interrupted***.  If the Spot price goes above your bid price, AWS will terminate your spot instance and your processing on that instance will be interrupted.  This is discussed on [AWS docs site](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-spot-instances.html).

AWS highlights some common use cases [here](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/details/):

- Analytics
- Big Data
- Geospatial Analysis
- Financial Modeling and Analysis
- Image and Media Encoding
- Testing
- Web Crawling
- Geospatial Analysis

AWS recommends using Spot instances to cut cost for typically expensive jobs in the cloud; not for specific technologies that you are asking about.  If your application can be re-designed to be distributed, scalable, and fault tolerant, you should look to take advantage of spot instances and save money over dedicated or on demand instances.

If you are flexible and can use DynamoDB (the AWS nosql db), [there is some support for using it over MongoDB because of simplicity and there are no servers to admin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28910064/819019).